# How to flash an ISO for Ubuntu installation to a flash drive using Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: lubuntu, live-usb

I need to flash a Ubuntu ISO image to my flash drive, but I'm running OS X 10.6, which isn't supported by Etcher. Is there any way to do this?

(I'm going to flash the lubuntu ISO, specifically.)

Comment: This is not about Ubuntu and you should ask on Ask Different. Anyways, the `dd` command is available on OS X 10.6 so you can use that.